# Problema con fotos en dompdf - laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, dompdf

estoy teniendo un problema para mostrar unas imágenes que tengo en el storage, subo una imagen, almaceno la ruta en la base de datos y la guardo en la carpeta storage y una subcarpeta llamada fotos (storage/fotos/imagen.png), se sube y la puedo ver una vista sin problemas, pero al tratar de verla en dompdf no me la muestra, me muestra asi:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el blade del pdf la llamda a la imagen la tenia asi:
`<img src="{{ asset('fotos/'.$imagen->ruta) }}" class="imgMant" >`

El filesytem lo tengo asi:

'public' => [
'driver' => 'local',
'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
'visibility' => 'public',
],

Tengo creado el enlace simblico del storage tambien...

He probado con asset, con url y nada, alguien ha pasado por lo mismo que me pudiera asesorar por favor

Saludos cordiales